# Routing conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, nested

my routing looks like this:

```
Improvement::Application.routes.draw do

#Protocols
resources :protocols

#Improvements
 root :to => 'pimps#index', :as => 'pimps'
 get    '/new(.:format)',       :to => 'pimps#new',     :as => 'new_pimp'
 get    '/:id/edit(.:format)',  :to => 'pimps#edit',    :as => 'edit_pimp'
 get    '/:id/(.:format)',      :to => 'pimps#show',    :as => 'pimp'
 post   '/(.:format)',          :to => 'pimps#create'
 put    '/:id(.:format)',       :to => 'pimps#update'
 patch  '/:id(.:format)',       :to => 'pimps#update'
 delete '/:id(.:format)',       :to => 'pimps#destroy'

#One Pager (nested in Improvements) 
 get    '/:pimp_id/onepager/new(.:format)',     :to => 'mepagers#new',      :as => 'new_mepager'
 get    '/:pimp_id/onepager/edit(.:format)',    :to => 'mepagers#edit',     :as => 'edit_mepager'
 get    '/:pimp_id/onepager(.:format)',         :to => 'mepagers#show',     :as => 'mepager'
 post   '/:pimp_id/onepager(.:format)',         :to => 'mepagers#create',   :as => 'create_mepager'
 put    '/:pimp_id/onepager(.:format)',         :to => 'mepagers#update'
 patch  '/:pimp_id/onepager(.:format)',         :to => 'mepagers#update'
 delete '/:pimp_id/onepager(.:format)',         :to => 'mepagers#destroy'

#Business Case (nested in Improvements) 
 get    '/:pimp_id/bcase/new(.:format)',    :to => 'bcases#new',        :as => 'new_bcase'
 get    '/:pimp_id/bcase/edit(.:format)',   :to => 'bcases#edit',       :as => 'edit_bcase'
 get    '/:pimp_id/bcase(.:format)',        :to => 'bcases#show',       :as => 'bcase'
 post   '/:pimp_id/bcase(.:format)',        :to => 'bcases#create',     :as => 'create_bcase'
 put    '/:pimp_id/bcase(.:format)',        :to => 'bcases#update'
 patch  '/:pimp_id/bcase(.:format)',        :to => 'bcases#update'
 delete '/:pimp_id/bcase(.:format)',        :to => 'bcases#destroy'

#Organisation Units
resources :org_units

end
```

Now if I call `http://localhost:3000/protocols` everything works fine and I get to the protocols page. But if I call `http://localhost:3000/org_units` rails tries to use the pimps_controller somehow and searchs fir a `pimp`-object with id='org_units'. If I specify the routes and controller like this

```
get '/org_units(.:format)', :to => 'org_units#new',     :as => 'org_units'
```

the same error occurs.

I tried to find out if theres a difference in my code between `protocols` and `org_unit` but I couldnt find any.

So maybe you know where my mistake lays.

Best regards.

Comment: Try adding the `resources :org_units` above `pimps routes`.I  mean add it just below the `resources :protocols`

Comment: Thanks, but trial and error already got me there. But thanks for that quick response!

Comment: Anyways, glad you got it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it. Obviously its important in which order I write my routes.rb! Putting `resources :org_units` on top did the trick!